# How to set work styles to Lock-Modify-Unlock tfs?

Tags: tfs

My team using TFS to control sourve code, now I want to change work styles to Lock-Modify-Unlock ( Only one person is allowed to check out file at a time ), so how to do it ?

Comment: May I ask why? That kind of workflow is considered a poor practice and is very antiquated these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[lock command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/lock-command?view=vsts)** to **temporarily** prevent changes to a particular file or folder in the source control server. This can be helpful if you want to change an item in your workspace and then check it in without being forced to resolve any merge conflicts. **Only one user at a time may hold a lock on a particular file or folder.**

More details please refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/understand-lock-types?view=vsts).

If you want to achieve "Only one person is allowed to check out file at a time ", you have to use Check-out lock through **server workspace**. In Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012, **check-out locks are generally not effective because of local workspaces** (see [*Decide between using a local or a server workspace*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=vsts)). Specifically, check-out locks are:

- Not enforceable because other users might be using local workspaces.
- Not available if you are using a local workspace.
- Disabled if a member of the Administrators security group of your
  team project collection has enabled asynchronous checkout for your
  team's server workspaces.